# I am trying to train my custom model. However i gave not subscriptable error. What should i do?

Tags: tensorflow, object, model, detection, box

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-8e6dca8c373a> in <module>()
     79 
     80 vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(image_np, 
---> 81                                                    output_dict['detection_boxes'],
     82                                                    output_dict['detection_classes'],
     83                                                    output_dict['detection_scores'],

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0):

I am by no means an expert, but it looks like your output_dict might be missing/has type None? How is that dict generated?

But more info is definitely needed here. People on this site cant really help you if you don't show the code...